# Bluemix - Insights for Twitter results missing relevant tweets?

Tags: twitter, ibm-cloud

I'm using the IBM Insights for Twitter service on Bluemix and need to extract all the tweets of specific users. The result set doesn't seem to be complete. Does anyone have some suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Using "from:account123" in your search query will return tweets from a specific account. You may not receive all their tweets if:

1. You're searching the Decahose, which is a 10% random sample of Tweets,
   or
2. The author's tweet precedes the set of Tweets indexed by the
   service.

Alternatively, you can use the service's PowerTrack feature to create a rule track that collects all Tweets from a specific author. Unlike the decahose stream, tracks grant you access to the Twitter firehose (100%). The PowerTrack feature is available through the service's Entry Plan.